# Xcode 10 NavigationBar icons not appearing on some devices

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, uinavigationitem, xcode10

I am using `Xcode 10` today, during development and testing I noticed that icons did not appear in iPhone 5s, iPhone 6s, iPhone 7s, just work on iPhone X, I set this icons by using xCode `storyboard`, I attached images to make my question more clear.
Thanks.

*** please check the NavigationBar ***

iPhone 6s

[image]

iPhone X

[image: iPhone X]

Comment: Updated title to mention it's in the navigation as I just spent the first minute comparing the screenshots. Might be worth updating the images to just show the navigation bars. Show how those items are built, show some code

Comment: Thanks for your help, I work on another project and we have the problem in the whole app, not just navigationBar, I don't use the code in this program just I use the storyboard to set this icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this bug with xCode 10, sometimes icons not appears not only in Navigation in all the app views, but some people also said: "The fix was setting color profile to sRGB.", I did it and works with some icons and with the others not, I said maybe this issue with CocaPods but not it, when I used xCode 10 beta version, all icons that missed work like a charm, but Apple not accept beta version release in their AppStore, after two days of searching I ran my code again on xCode 9.4 and its worked like a charm and I realized my app to AppStore.