# Xcode 10.1 issue with uicontrols on Navigation bar are not appearing in certain devices

Tags: uinavigationbar, xcode10.1

Navigation bar uicontrols are not appearing in certain devices on iOS 11 and iOS 12, if the code is compiled on Xcode 10.1. 
Works perfectly fine if the code is compiled on Xcode 9.2.

Found simmilar ssue reported - [Xcode 10 NavigationBar icons not appearing on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497325/xcode-10-navigationbar-icons-not-appearing-on-some-devices)

but the suggested solution to change the settings did not solve the issue.

Wondering someone else has seen the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with XCode 10.1 navigation bar. By mistake made the following change in one common place before presenting all my UIViewControllers which made all the navigation bars go transparent and the text in white and the icons in white disappered.

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[SSCTheme colorFromPalette:PaletteColorWhite]];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

Sorry for raising this issue.